# How to calculate R squared and multiple R squared from rlm output?

Tags: r, lm, rlm

I have a question that requires me to find and report the adjusted R^2 and multiple R^2 values from a linear regression model. The problem is that the question only tells me to use rlm() from MASS and nothing about the inbuilt lm() function.
[image]

The one above is the rlm output, and the one below is the lm output for the same variables. How can I obtain the multiple R-squared and adjusted R-squared from the rlm model?

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).   Computer output should be pasted as text, not as an image, please!

Comment: Please tell us *which* $R^2$ you want to report.  The default output of `MASS:::summary.rlm` weights the residuals.  In your example, that results in them being even *smaller* than in the `lm` fit (an impossibility for the unweighted residuals).  Thus, there are at least two versions of $R^2:$ one that uses the actual residuals and another that uses the weights.  Note that the latter might be difficult or impossible to interpret when some of the weights are small.  (Inspect the vector in the `$w` component of the `rlm` object.)